# Exporting single features in QGIS 2.12.3 with a transparent background

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to export single features for an animated power point presentation and I need them to have the ability to overlay one another as they appear in the presentation.

Is there a way to export features with a transparent background in QGIS?

When I try changing the background color in the Project Properties there is no option for a transparent or clear background.

Answer (score 1):

[See this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123484/exporting-gis-images-with-transparency), I believe it covers exactly what you are looking for (the two questions might in fact benefit from being merged?)